# How to write jquery input autocomplete

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I am trying to write an autocomplete for an input tag, the array for autocomplete is coming from the result of an ajax call. i have tried manier times but it is still not fetching the data for input search. I am using Jquery 1.11.3 version.please help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to bind jquery autocomplete once you receive response from the AJAX call. It is not straightforward. You need to use autocomplete API such as **select, source and focus** events to make it work. Below is the illustration of binding an user list from the ajax response to the autocomplete input box.

In the **select** function you need to search the input value with name property of all users and filter only those records. This snippet is nothing but searching users from list of users array based on **name** property.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>jQuery UI Fetch Users</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function () {
            fetchUsers();
        });

        function fetchUsers() {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/',
                type: 'GET',

                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",

                success: function (data) {
                    console.log(data);
                    if (data) {
                        $("#users").autocomplete({
                            source: function (request, response) {
                                response($.map(data, function (obj, key) {
                                    var name = obj.name.toUpperCase();

                                    if (name.indexOf(request.term.toUpperCase()) != -1) {
                                        return {
                                            label: obj.name,
                                            value: obj.id
                                        }
                                    } else {
                                        return null;
                                    }
                                }));

                            },
                            focus: function (event, ui) {
                                event.preventDefault();
                            },
                           
                            select: function (event, ui) {
                                event.preventDefault();
                                $('#users').val(ui.item.label);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                },

                error: function (error) {
                    console.log(error);
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>

    <div class="ui-widget">
        <label for="tags">Users: </label>
        <input id="users">
    </div>


</body>

</html>
```

For more details about the autocomplete API refer [jQuery UI documentation](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/).

Comment: Thank you @prathameshk73. I was having Z index issue so couldnt see the autocomplete results. its working now thanks

Answer (score 0):

use this jquery library to make dynamic autocomplete
https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

Comment: Thank you @Hameed for the quick response. I tried using the library but it's not working. Here is the piece of code I tried using.               :

$("#tags").autocomplete({
    source: yerler,
    focus: function (event, ui) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $("#tags").val(ui.item.label);
    },
    select: function (event, ui) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $("#projeKatmanRaporCbx").val(ui.item.value);
        $("#tags").val(ui.item.label);
    }
})